# All unique samples from a data set in R

Tags: r

Here's my data

```
z<- c("COP","CHK","BP","BHI","CVX")
```

if i do

```
 sample(z,3,replace=FALSE)
```

This will give me 1 unique random sample of 3 from my data set.

I want to find all possible unique samples of 3 from my data set. In this case there will be 10 outcomes.

But how do I write a R code for it?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `combn` to get the unique combinations

```
t(combn(z, 3))
```

If we need to `sample` it

```
t(combn(sample(z), 3))
```